# trying to compile an rc file(Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++, compilation, ide, codeblocks

Im trying to compile an rc file in code::blocks but im getting some errors. Here's the file:

```
#include "I:/Win32/Win32_SimpleMenu/resource.h"

IDR_MYMENU MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&file"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "E&xit", ID_FILE_EXIT
    END

    POPUP "&Stuff"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&Go", ID_STUFF_GO
        MENUITEM "G&o somewhere else", 0, GRAYED
    END
END

IDI_MYICON ICON "menu_one.ico"
```

the compiler says it is compiling the rc file, but it does nothing. After cancling i get:

> ||can't open file `prompt': No such file or directory|
>   ||preprocessing failed.|
>   ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Thanks

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5565018#5565018